# Getting org.hibernate.DuplicateMappingException: Duplicate class/entity mapping in hibernate3.0

Tags: hibernate, tomcat, java-8

I am trying to run a webapp using `hibernate3.0` with `struts2-core-2.1.6` on `Tomcat7.0.55` with `JDK8`. I am getting  `org.hibernate.DuplicateMappingException: Duplicate class/entity mapping com.poste.struts2.bean.CityDetails` . My `hibernate.cfg.xml` is:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
  "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
  "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
     <session-factory>     
        <property name="connection.useUnicode">true</property> 
        <property name="connection.characterEncoding">UTF-8</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb</property>
        <property name="connection.username">uname</property>
        <property name="connection.password">pass</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</property>     
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property> 
        <property name="format_sql">true</property> 
        <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</property>         
        <mapping class="com.poste.struts2.bean.CityDetails" />
        </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

The class code is:

```
package com.poste.struts2.bean;
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;
@Entity
@Table(name = "city_master")
public class CityDetails implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 9149826260758390091L;
    private Long cityId;
    private String cityName;
    private String cityStatus;
    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name="generator", strategy="increment")
    @GeneratedValue(generator="generator")
    @Column(name = "CITM_CITY_ID")
    public Long getCityId(){
        return this.cityId;
    }
    public void setCityId(Long cityId){
        this.cityId = cityId;
    }
    @Column(name = "CITM_CITY_NAME", columnDefinition = "nvarchar", length = 100)
    public String getCityName(){
        return this.cityName;
    }
    public void setCityName(String cityName){
        this.cityName = cityName;
    }
    @Column(name = "CITM_STATUS")
    public String getCityStatus() {
        return cityStatus;
    }
    public void setCityStatus(String cityStatus) {
        this.cityStatus = cityStatus;
    }
}
```

My WEB-INF/lib contains

```
activation-1.1.jar
antlr-2.7.6.jar
commons-beanutils.jar
commons-collections-3.1.jar
commons-fileupload-1.2.1.jar
commons-io-1.3.2.jar
commons-lang-2.3.jar
commons-logging-1.0.4.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
ejb3-persistence.jar
freemarker-2.3.16.jar
hibernate-annotations.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations.jar
hibernate-validator.jar
hibernate3.jar
hsqldb.jar
httpclient-4.0.jar
itext-2.1.7.jar
java-mail-1.4.4.jar
JavaBridge.jar
javassist.jar
javax.persistence.jar
jcommon-1.0.16.jar
jfreechart-1.0.13.jar
json.jar
jta-1.1.jar
junit-3.8.1.jar
log4j-1.2.14.jar
mysql-connector-java-5.1.32.jar
ognl-2.6.11.jar
php-servlet.jar
poi-3.2-FINAL-20081019.jar
slf4j-api-1.5.8.jar
slf4j-log4j12-1.5.8.jar
slf4j-simple-1.5.8.jar
struts2-convention-plugin-2.1.6.jar
struts2-core-2.1.6.jar
struts2-dojo-plugin-2.2.3.jar
struts2-fullhibernatecore-plugin-1.4-GA.jar
struts2tutorial.jar
xwork-2.1.2.jar
```

The COLUMNS are:

```
CITM_CITY_ID    decimal(10,0)
CITM_CITY_NAME  varchar(200 
CITM_STATUS     varchar(20)
```

Any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is you have mapping for `com.poste.struts2.bean.CityDetails` in hibernate config file, as well as you have mapping for it in annotations.

Either remove following line from `hibernate.cfg.xml`

```
 <mapping class="com.poste.struts2.bean.CityDetails" />
```

or remove annotations in `CityDetails` class.

Comment: Thanks a lot . It has been fixed.

Answer (score 11):

Such duplicate may also be caused by renaming the mapped class and building the application without wiping out the old classes (e.g. building with Maven without running "mvn clean" first.)

Comment: Well thank you very much, that sounds like my problem.

Comment: Yeah, my case :)

Answer (score 2):

That is very correct answer by **Darshan** but, this error may come even if you mention same class mapping again by mistake. I had received this error when i mentioned

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean"
        p:dataSource-ref="writeDataSource"
        p:mappingResources="com/my/test/Test1.hbm.xml,com/my/test/Test2.hbm.xml,com/my/test/Test1.hbm.xml" />
```

like in above mapping I have put **Test1.hbm.xml** again instead **Test3.hbm.xml**

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem, and it was due that the some jars were duplicated, and I had to remove them and then cleanup Jenkins (build tool I use). Don't know about the reason of this duplicated jars.

Answer (score 0):

No two different hibernate mapping files should have same property or id tags.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you just have to clean your project and rebuild to solve the problem, as myself

Comment: i was facing the problem before

Answer (score 0):

With hibernate 5.4.11 I also got this error message after defining two JPQL queries with the same name:

```
@NamedQuery(
        name = "Employee.getAll",
        query = "SELECT e FROM Employee e"
)
@NamedQuery(
        name = "Employee.findOlderThan",
        query = "SELECT e FROM Employee e WHERE e.age > :age"
)
@NamedQuery(
        name = "Employee.getAll",
        query = "SELECT e FROM Employee e"
)
```